# Mapping multiple paths to a single Zuul route

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

Currently, the way I have my application.yml file configured is each unique path has is mapped to its own zuul service and the zuul service is calling the same API:

```
zuul:
  routes:
    myserver1:
      path: /mypath1/**

    myserver2:
      path: /mypath2/**

    myserver3:
      path: /mypath3/**
```

I was wondering if there was a way to map all of these path's to one service, because potentially there could be more unique paths added that will call the same service and I wanted to design the yml file in a more scalable fashion. I tried adding a prefix to the multiple paths to map all of them to one service, but for my specific use case it's not applicable.

Comment: Not currently, spring cloud gateway supports this.